# packages installed after activating conda environment

Tags: anaconda

I want to know after creating and activating a conda environment in terminal. Say `venv`:

```
conda create -n venv
source activate venv
```

Then the prompt will come with the enviroment name `(venv)`.
**would the packages installed   (say `conda install tensorflow` without `--name venv`)** **after environment activation only effect inside the environment `venv`**? Or **would it affect outside `venv`**?
I don't want to mess up my environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only affect the environment that you activated.